# Erlang: qlc:info throws an error while qlc:eval does not - why?

Tags: erlang, sql-execution-plan

Works

```
root@test # erl
Erlang R14B02 (erts-5.8.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> Tmp = ets:new(test, [bag]), Ref = make_ref(),
1> qlc:eval(qlc:q([Ref1 || Ref1 <- ets:table(Tmp), Ref =:= Ref1])).
[]
2> qlc:info(qlc:q([Ref1 || Ref1 <- ets:table(Tmp), Ref =:= Ref1])).
"ets:table(16400,\n          [{traverse,\n            {select,\n             [{'$1',\n               [{'=:=',{const,#Ref<0.0.0.29>},'$1'}],\n               ['$1']}]}}])"
3> halt().
```

Does not work

```
root@test # erl
Erlang R14B02 (erts-5.8.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> Tmp = ets:new(test, [bag]), Ref = make_ref(),
1> qlc:eval(qlc:q([Ref1 || {Ref1} <- ets:table(Tmp), Ref =:= Ref1])).
[]
2> qlc:info(qlc:q([Ref1 || {Ref1} <- ets:table(Tmp), Ref =:= Ref1])).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,{1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ",["Ref"]]}}
     in function  qlc:abstract/3
     in call from qlc:abstract/3
     in call from qlc:abstract/4
     in call from qlc:info/2
3> halt().
```

I can't understand why. Discovered this error on a much more complex query that I'm not able to explain and profile because of this error.

Comment: Interesting that the qlc:info/1 succeeds if you call it twice.

Comment: Can you post a PoC? I'm not sure I've understood what you mean.

Comment: This is an old question, and I'm surprised it still not answered or closed. My question is why do you store the references in the table as {Ref} instead of just Ref?

Comment: @Roberto Aloi. The 2nd run is succeeding because the 1st run fail results in ets table being lost (shell process dies because of exception). Thus qlc info is not doing parse_exprs for this query handle and thus it passes. (Need to do more debugging to know why it does not do parse_exprs in this case)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7.2]. Same for @Vinod's related issue in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315036/2482570. Maybe this was a bug that was fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the post is very old, I wanted to understand the behavior. Please correct me wherever there is something wrong in my understanding.

Consider the following change in the code

```
1> Tmp = ets:new(test, [bag]), Ref = my_own_ref,
qlc:info(qlc:q([Ref1 || Ref1 <- ets:table(Tmp), (Ref1 =:= Ref) ])).
"ets:table(16400,\n          [{traverse,\n            {select,[{'$1',[{'=:=','$1
',{const,my_own_ref}}],['$1']}]}}])"
2> qlc:info(qlc:q([{Val1} || {Ref1,Val1} <- ets:table(Tmp), (Ref1 =:= Ref) ])).
"ets:match_spec_run(ets:lookup(16400, my_own_ref),\n                   ets:match
_spec_compile([{{'$1','$2'},[],[{{'$2'}}]}]))"
```

The change in the output is that match_spec_run is used in the second case(qlc handles are different). This means there is a change how the qlc info needs to get the data from the qlc handle.

The below code gives error

```
1> Tmp = ets:new(test, [bag]), Ref = make_ref().
#Ref<0.0.0.25>
2> qlc:info(qlc:q([{Val1} || {Ref1,Val1} <- ets:table(Tmp), (Ref1 =:= Ref) ])).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value
                    {error,{1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ",["Ref"]]}}
     in function  qlc:abstract/3 (d:/workspace/test/src/qlc.erl, line 1177)
     in call from qlc:abstract/3 (d:/workspace/test/src/qlc.erl, line 1196)
     in call from qlc:abstract/4 (d:/workspace/test/src/qlc.erl, line 1142)
     in call from qlc:info/2 (d:/workspace/test/src/qlc.erl, line 445)
```

When debugging the code of qlc found that, for match_spec_run related query handle the qlc:info uses [abstract format](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/absform.html) function [erl_parse:parse_exprs/1](http://ww.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_parse.html#parse_exprs-1) to get the parse tree. But the problem in this case is that the Erlang reference has no parse tree!! For simple understanding `NewRef = #Ref<0.0.0.134>.` and also pid `NewPid = <0.34.0>.` gives syntax error, they can only be values bound to a variable and compiler cannot interpret/parse them. Thus in this case it results in the error.